# Make second line of text text align under first line of text

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of text that I am trying to align correctly. I have a hyphen that comes before the first line of text. The problem is that the second line of text is sitting under the hyphen as a pose to the starting text of the first line. I have an image of what is happening to explain better.

[image]

Here is my code

```
  <div>
    <span>-</span> 
    <span>The fund or the employer gave a housing loan to the member and the member owes money on the loan.</span>
  </div>
```

If I add margin left to the second span it only adds margin to the first line. Also I am not allowed  to make the text fit on a single line. It need to go over to the new line like this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flexbox`

```css
.block{
  display:flex;
}
.mr-5{
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
    <span class="mr-5">-</span> 
    <span>The fund or the employer gave a housing loan to the member and the member owes money on the loan. The fund or the employer gave a housing loan to the member and the member owes money on the loan.The fund or the employer gave a housing loan to the member and the member owes money on the loan.</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not try using the "pre" tag for html.

Text in a "pre" element is displayed in a fixed-width font, and the text preserves both spaces and line breaks. The text will be displayed exactly as written in the HTML source code.

See if that works for you.